# Where can I find the URLs that the AWS Ruby SDK connects to?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the AWS Ruby SDK for a project, but I've been having some issues with it behind our network proxy. To that end, the infrastructure guys have asked me to find them the URLs that the SDK is trying to connect to.

I'm using the ElasticBeanstalk and S3 services in the SDK, so I need those API URLs that the Ruby SDK connects to.

I've browsed a bit through the code, but it's pretty vast, so I haven't been able to find anything yet. Could anyone help me find those URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in their "[endpoints.json](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/endpoints.json)" file.

It contains a long list of different hosts that look like what your infrastructure guys would want to see.

Download that file, then use `grep hostname endpoints.json > hostnames.txt` to extract the information into a file for them to see.

And, BTW, that file seems to disappear after the gem is installed. I think they're using it to build a table used at run-time. I haven't looked in the code to see for sure, but it seems like that because it's not in the installed gem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the log level and set the correct logger for AWS SDK.

```
require 'logger'
AWS.config(:logger => Logger.new($stdout), :loglevel => :debug)
```

Then monitor the requests being made.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/Core/Configuration.html